# Как изменить изображение на кнопке QPushButton при на наведении на нее курсора мыши?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qss

Главный и единственный корнтейнер окна `box` содержит в себе всего лишь один виджет - кнопку `button`.

`button` представляет из себя кнопку с изображением. Это изображение мне необходимо изменять на другое, когда на кнопку будет наведен курсор мыши, и возвращать предыдущее изображение, если курсор мыши будет убран с кнопки.

**Идеальным вариантом было бы изменение таблицы стиля кнопки** текст курсивом. Насколько я знаю, в таблице стиля можно указать пункт `QPushButton:hover`, который как раз позволяет контролировать нахождение курсора на кнопке. Но с помощью него я умею только изменять цвет.

Пожалуйста, скажите, как можно решить мою проблему?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        button.setStyleSheet(qss)
        button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('-_1.png'))
        button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 20))

        box.addWidget(button)


qss = '''QPushButton {
             border: none;
             margin: 0px;
             padding: 0px;
         }'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, используйте фильтр событий над кнопкой. Установка фильтра выполняется через метод [installEventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter), а обработка в переопределенном методе [eventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter).

В нем для конкретных событий меняйте иконку кнопки.

Пример:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.button.setStyleSheet(qss)
        self.button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('-_1.png'))
        self.button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 20))
        self.button.installEventFilter(self)

        box.addWidget(self.button)

    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        # Если событие от кнопки
        if object == self.button:
            if event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
                self.button.setText('Курсор тут')
                return False
            elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
                self.button.setText('Курсор покинул кнопку')
                return False

        return super().eventFilter(object, event)


qss = '''QPushButton {
             border: none;
             margin: 0px;
             padding: 0px;
         }'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

`border-image:` вам в помощь

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        button.setFixedSize(30, 20)                    # +
        button.setStyleSheet(qss)
#        button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('im.png'))
#        button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 20))

        box.addWidget(button)

qss = '''
QPushButton {
    border: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-image: url(Ok.png);        
}
QPushButton:hover {
    border-image: url(im.png);
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо! К сожалению, не могу отметить два ответа правильными:(

Comment: @MAXIM045 Пожалуйста. Печалиться будете когда ответов не будет вообще :)